# Heap insertion and deletion

Tags: algorithm, heap, graph-algorithm, binary-heap

Firstly, I have to delete 7 from the heap and after that add 17 and 14.

[image]

The problem is I dont know what that heap is. Is it a min heap? or a binomial heap?

Can any of you explain me how to do it (or/and) draft each operation?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a heap. Even if you try to make sense of the nonsensical way in which it's drawn, any possible choice of the root produces a tree that violates the heap invariant.

Comment: According to the excercise I have to do it is a heap. Anyway I have the same opinion as you do. I can't recognize a heap from that draft.

Comment: Actually, that could be a [pairing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap), with 3 as the root. It's very oddly drawn, but it appears to satisfy the conditions of the pairing heap.

Comment: @JimMischel: If your hypothesis is correct, isn't there then a bug in the heap at 11 (since 10 is smaller)?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Possibly. I haven't had the time to sit down and construct an example case, but I do remember that pairing heap can create some pretty non-intuitive trees.

Comment: If you swap 11 and 10, then it will become a min heap with 3 as the root.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I retract my hypothesis. That can't be a pairing heap. The root node of a pairing heap has no siblings; it would only have a left (child) pointer. To be a valid pairing heap, node 5 would be a sibling of 6, just as 7 and 8 are siblings. The 11,10 thing is no problem because with the left-child-right-sibling arrangement used by pairing heap, 10 and 11 would be siblings and the correct node (10) would be selected as the new root in the pair-and-combine operation when node 6 is deleted.

Comment: Correction: 7 and 9 are siblings of 6. 8 is a child of 7.

Answer (score 0):

Any element inside the heap can be deleted in `O(logn)` by simply ***replacing*** it with the ***last leaf*** and then applying the [Heapify operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) on the ***last leaf***.

You have to add new node at the first empty leaf you get in right-bottom side and then heapify that leaf.

Heapify:

- Repeatedly exchange the new element (general: the element that
  violates the heap conditions) with its parent node as long as it is
  smaller than the parent and it is not the root.
- Repeatedly exchange
  the new element with the child with the smallest value, until the new
  element becomes a leave or both child nodes are bigger than the
  element itself.

Comment: It appears you're talking about a binary heap. Whereas it's true that you can delete in O(logn) time, it takes O(n) time to find the node to be deleted.

Comment: yeah, swapping 11 and 10 makes the given tree a binary min heap with 3 as the root.

Comment: Not really. A binary heap is supposed to be balanced, with the leaf level left-filled. Otherwise the calculation for finding child nodes doesn't work.